# How to I get access to the f7 instance when using React

Tags: reactjs, html-framework-7

I am using 3.0.0-beta.15 of framework7-react. When using the vanilla version of framework7 you create a new instance like this.

`var app = new Framework7({});`

I cant figure out how to access the created instance (app) in react.

`import {App} from 'framework7-react';
 <App params={{ theme, routes }} ref={f7 => window.f7 = f7}`

In version 1 of framework7-react you could pass the "onFramework7Init" prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can use `this.$f7` inside any of your component and it will reference the framework 7 instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the instance like this:

```
import Framework7 from 'framework7/components/app/app-class'; //auto-import
...
const router = Framework7.instance.views.main.router; //.instance not in .d.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I get f7 instance globally:

```
import Framework7 from 'framework7/framework7.esm.bundle';

export default class UIService {
     public static showToast(options: ToastOptions) {

     // @ts-ignore
     const f7: Framework7 = Framework7.instance;
     f7.toast.show({ text: options.content, position: 'center' });
    }
}
```